# Execute a PHP file with Cron ONLY

Tags: php, apache, shell, cron

I've got a PHP script that needs to be executed once a day, at 3:05am Pacific time.  I've currently got the script in the root of my site (as in, http://example.com/script.php), and as such, it's executable by anyone who navigates to it in their browser.  My server is laid out like this:

**/home/[user]/example.com/**

Where the *example.com* folder is the root of that domain.  I read the other thread about this:

[PHP & cron: security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387569/php-cron-security-issues)

where it was said that I should move the script outside the public directory, so in my case I would move it to the *[user]* folder.  Currently my Cron job command looks like this:

**/usr/local/php5/bin/php /home/[user]/example.com/script.php**

(I'm using pseudo-names of course.)  Would I simply move the file and change the command to:

**/usr/local/php5/bin/php /home/[user]/script.php**

And it would run normally, yet be unavailable to the public?  Since the script is already running through Cron, it's already set up using absolute paths (instead of relative ones) to the files that it needs to include, so this should be a simple move and edit, right?

Comment: try it and see?  it should be though

Comment: Try it and see? There shouldn't be any issues unless you have shared hosting and can't move files outside your public directory.

Comment: I do have shared hosting, but I can move files outside the public directory.  I have access to /home/[user], which is outside the public directory tree, so I could move it there.  The only problem with just trying it is I won't know if it's worked until 3:05am tomorrow.

Comment: You could always create simple script and test your cron entry against that. The cron entry doesn't have to be at 3:05.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was just moving it out of the public directory, into my home folder. CRON is still able to access and execute it from there. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @yoeriboven, I didn't down vote, but to me even though it's the OP's own solution, it isn't quite answering the question originally asked, it is side stepping it. I came here looking for a method for scripts that are in the public directory, and the other answers are better for that task.

Answer (score 9):

You have several options:

- move that out of your web directory
- add some checking, eg:

  ```
  <?php

  if( ! isset($argv) )   
      die("cannot run!");
  ```
- check what mode your script run:

  ```
  $isCLI = ( php_sapi_name() == 'cli' );
  if( !$isCLI )
      die("cannot run!");
  ```

Comment: All you need to do is check if $argv is set. It wont be set on a regular web request.

Comment: Depending on the configuration `$argv` is set via `register_globals`. I wouldn't rely on it ;) Looking for the used sapi (`PHP_SAPI === 'cli'`) feels safer.

Comment: Since register globals isn't a thing, and hasn't been for some time, just the $argv approach is sufficient at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us about the purpose of the script, if it's doing simple stuff for example mysql pruning:

```
5 3 * * * * root mysql -u username -e "UPDATE users SET days = days-1;"
```

might be better, similarly:

```
5 3 * * * * root /usr/local/php5/bin/php -r "$normal = 'php';code();$here"
```

may do the trick?

Comment: It's not complex, but it's doing more than simple mysql operations.  It's grabbing information from an external API, reading it, formatting it, checking for duplicate entries, then inserting it into the database (if no duplicate existed).  It's something I need to do with PHP, just in case something happens and the Cron doesn't execute, so I have to force the update (that happened this morning)